# A science-verb? Sciencing?

Tags: verbs

Is there a verb to the word *science*? Could you say *sciencing* (i.e. "in the Process of making/generating science")?

Of course there is the word research, which is both a verb and a noun. But in the noun form, "research" and "science" seem to differ a bit if you ask me.

Comment: Do you have more context?

Comment: @simchona: No, I don't. It just occurred to me.

Comment: Is this following the philosophy of "There is no noun that cannot be verbed?"

Comment: @Gnawme: At least that seems to hold for the noun *verb*. Language is weird :)

Comment: "Verbing weirds language"  Calvin & Hobbes

Comment: It would not surprise me to hear, for example, that when an advertiser decides to put a "scientist" in an ad, with a white coat and a clipboard, that they referred to this as "sciencing" the campaign. I have no reason to suppose they do call it this, but it is the sort of thing that happens to words. But I've never heard "science" as a verb.

Comment: *"I'm sciencing as fast as I can science!"* - http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Futurama:_Bender%27s_Big_Score#Professor_Farnsworth

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that there is no exact verb counterpart to the noun, since there are very many things you can do that involve science. Making a rocket and figuring out the chemical composition of something are both examples of science, but they are very different in terms of what kind of thing you are doing.

Some common ones might be *experiment*, *study*, *invent*, and *investigate.*

Or, playfully (read: don't put this in anything formal), I might *do science*.

Comment: Both examples you give can be called *research* as well, and "doing science on them" could be expressed as *researching* them. So your statement why it makes sense that there is no such verb seems at least a bit far fetched to me. Did I perhaps miss some finer point?

Comment: Making a rocket would not normally be considered research. (I'm talking about building one, not coming up with a brand new theory of rockets)

Comment: Oh, I see. Nevertheless, I still cannot relate to your argument. Anyway, *doing science* is probably the usual construction for this issue. But I like *sciencing* for its whimsicality. :)

Comment: @bitmask Also, you can research something without doing any science.  You can research a painter, research a paper for English class, research a raid boss strategy for World of Warcraft, etc.  If you made a Venn diagram for research and science, they'd definitely have quite a bit of overlap, but neither one is contained wholly within the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is a verb *scientize*, meaning ‘to make scientific; to give (something) a scientific character, basis, or rationale; to organize on scientific principles’ (OED). Not sure I’d recommend it, though.